# How can I preconfigure a wireless network I haven't seen yet?

Tags: wifi, raspbian, ifconfig, etc

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with some specialized software and with the intent to ship it out to a customer and just have them plug it in and work. However, since the customer is in a different location, it will obviously have never connected to their wifi network before. It would be ideal if I could configure it with the SSID and password (both of which I have) ahead of time so that when the customer plugs it in, they don't have to do anything (i.e. it just works).

Are there are command line utilities, or `/etc` files to edit, that will allow me to set up a wireless network ahead of time?

Comment: See https://debian-administration.org/article/312/Network_profiles_for_a_laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out... basically you have to edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file, and add an entry like this one:

```
network={
    ssid="My_Network_Name"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```